# how can I change the label name when the option value change?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have  a combo box and I like values are 1 and 3 inside the combobox. when the page loads default value is 1 and my default label name is 1.... if I select 2 on the combo box I like to make my label name 2.

```
function changeLabel(){

if (document.getElementById('conbobox').value !=1)
{document.getElementById('myLabel').label="2"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your markup, but I assume the element with id 'myLabel' is a div labeling your combobox element.  If that is the case, use

```
document.getElementById('myLabel').innerHTML = "2"
```